# Module removed but Tables remaining in database in Magento2

Tags: magento2, module, uninstall

I have created one module/extension using installer script in magento2.

After that I removed it, but tables in database still remain as it is.

can anyone tell me how to uninstall module/extension completely and remove extension's/module's  tables from database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you install the module via composer, you can have create the `Setup/Uninstall.php` file that will be executed when running `bin/magento module:uninstall -r [Namespace]_[Module]`.

The `Uninstall.php` file should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;

class Uninstall implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface
{
    public function uninstall(
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        if ($setup->tableExists('table_name_here')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->dropTable('table_name_here');
        }
    }
}
```

If you installed the module manually, you will need to cleanup your database manually also buy dropping the tables the module added.

Comment: I have installed module manually

Comment: Then you have to cleanup yourself the database.

Comment: I have this same issue. i have removed  tables manually but i can't reinstall it using `installer script`.